# Help with a proof of a consequence from the axioms of addition and multiplication

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, real-numbers, axioms

While reading through Analysis 1 by Vladimir A. Zorich, I encountered this proof which has this 1 step I can't understand. Here is the consequence and the proof:

For every $x\in \mathbb R$ the following is true

$$-x=(-1)\cdot x$$

*Proof.* $\ \ x+(-1)\cdot x=\underbrace{(1+(-1))\cdot x}_\text{Which of the axioms were used here ?}= 0 \cdot x=x \cdot 0 = 0$. The assumption follows from the uniqueness of the negative of a number.

*End of proof.*

The underbraced part is what I fail to understand. What addition and multiplication axioms were used in order to make that expression ?

Comment: Distributive law of real numbers

Comment: Please avoid the use of the "analysis" tag. Indeed the [tag info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/analysis/info) explicitly suggest to use a more specific tag.

Comment: @ArcticChar what is the issue with using the analysis tag?

Comment: @GrigoriPerelman Please see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28023/how-should-the-analysis-tag-be-used) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15206/why-is-the-tag-analysis-useful?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more information.

Comment: The upshot is: if analysis tag  is used alongside other "analysis" tag (say real-, complex-, functional-, ....), then it gives zero extra infomation. If analysis tag is used alone, then it's not specific enough.

Comment: @ArcticChar I understand, but nevertheless I don’t think it is deficitary in any way. Some people may explore the network using that particular tag and I put it there to reach those ones who do. Please don’t remove that tag from my posts in the future, except if I don’t put the more specific one also. Thanks for the insights on the topic

Comment: I will try to do that (in general when I edit a post I do not check who's the asker - that's irrelevant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $1\in\Bbb{R}$ is a special element of the set with the property that for every $x\in \Bbb{R}$, $1\cdot x = x\cdot 1 = x$. Next, we also use the distributive law that for all $a,b,c\in\Bbb{R}$, $a\cdot(b+c) = a\cdot b + a \cdot c$. Hence,
\begin{align}
x+ (-1)\cdot x &= 1 \cdot x + (-1)\cdot x \tag{property of $1$} \\
&= [1 + (-1)]\cdot x \tag{distributive law}
\end{align}
The rest of the proof follows once you establish that for every $x\in\Bbb{R}$, $0\cdot x = 0$.

Comment: Many thanks. Completely clear now.

Answer (score 1):

the principal is distribution:  $a(b+c) = ab + ac$.

So the proof goes like this:

$x + (-1)x = 1\cdot x + (-1)\cdot x$ (by existence and definition of multiplicative identity)

$=(1+(-1))\cdot x$ (by distribution)

$=0\cdot x$ (by definition of additive inverse)

$=x\cdot 0$ (commutivity of multiplication but I have no idea why he did this)

$= 0$ (This is *not* an axiom but a proposition can be proven that $0\cdot x = 0$.  Have you proven that yet?  Does Spivak use that as an axiom?)

Then by definition we have that for every $x$ there exists a unique $-(x)$ so that $x + (-x) = 0$.

If we ever have an $a$ so that $x + a = 0$ it must be that $a=-x$ as the multiplicative inverse is unique.  As $x + (-1)x =0$ it must be $(-1)x = -x$.

======

Prop:  $x\cdot 0 = 0$.

Pf: $x\cdot 0 + (-(x\cdot 0)) = 0$.  (Every element $a$, including $x\cdot 0$, has an additive inverse, $-a$, so that $a + (-a) =0$.)

$x\cdot(0 + 0) + (-(x\cdot 0)) = 0$ ($0=0+0$ because $0$ is the additive identity and $a +0 = a$ for all $a$, including when $a$ is $0$.)

$(x\cdot 0 + x\cdot 0) + (-(x\cdot 0)) = 0$ (distributivity)

$x\cdot 0 + (x\cdot 0 + (-(x\cdot 0)) = 0$ (associativity)

$x\cdot 0 + 0 = 0$ (definition of additive identity)

$x\cdot 0 = 0 $ ($a + 0= a$ for all $a$ by definition of additive identity.)